# d3js multiple bars in chart from single array element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[This fiddle pretty much explains what I'm trying to accomplish.](http://jsfiddle.net/johnfallen/WABXB/)

It shows the problem and a proposed solution, but I wonder if my solution is 'right'.

Basically I have JSON that represents a week of scores among teams.

```
games = [
    {
        hometeam : "scouts",
        homeTeamScore : "21",
        visitor : "sharks",
        visitorScore : "17"
    },
    {
        hometeam : "gators",
        homeTeamScore : "28",
        visitor : "wild cats",
        visitorScore : "24"
    }
]
```

How would one make a bar chart where each game outputs two bars representing each teams score (two bars from one element of the array)? It would look like this:

```
-----------------scouts 21
-----------sharks 17
-------------------gators 28
----------------wild cats 24
```

I cant seem to get my mind around how I can output each teams score using the single element in the array doing .data(games).enter().append() since I 'think' I can only output one entry for each array element.

I can do it if I generate my own array, not a problem (see the fiddle), but is that the best, most d3ish way to handle a situation like this?

Again: [here is the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/johnfallen/WABXB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common "trick" is to save the `.enter()` selection and operate on it multiple times. This achieves exactly what you want:

```
var divs = d3.select('.chart2')
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(data)
  .enter();

divs.insert('div')
  .attr("class", 'home')
  .style("width", function(d) {
      return d.hs * 10 + "px";
  })
  .text(function(d) { 
    return d.hnn + ' ' + d.hs; 
  });

divs.insert('div')
  .attr("class", 'visitor')
  .style("width", function(d) {
    return d.vs * 10 + "px";
  })
  .text(function(d) { 
    return d.vnn + ' ' + d.vs; 
  });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WABXB/1/).

Comment: SUPER DUPER PERFECT! Thank you mucho Lars. That's the one combination I didn't think about.